# How can I return results based on column from second inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

**tags:**

```
| id | title |
```

**categories**:

```
| tag_id (FK tags.id) | category_tag_id (FK tags.id) |
```

> category_tag_id references the tags.id because we're re-using the tags table (we can simply assign a category to a tag with this table

**articles**

```
| id | title | body | etc... |
```

**articles_tags**

```
| article_id (FK articles.id) | tag_id (FK tags.id) |
```

I'm trying to create a query which selects all the categories associated to this skill. We grab the categories by searching the tags that are linked in the **articles_tags** table, then we just need to check what categories are associated to those tags by checking the **categories** table.

Here is what I've tried

```
select tags.* 
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN categories ON tags.id = categories.tag_id
INNER JOIN article_tags ON article_tags.article_id = ID_OF_ARTICLE_WE_WANT_CATEGORIES_FROM
```

I also tried adding a

```
where article_id = ID_OF_ARTICLE_WE_WANT_CATEGORIES_FROM
```

However this query seems to return ALL the categories and not just the ones associated to the skill.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
select tags.* 
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN categories ON tags.id = categories.tag_id
INNER JOIN article_tags ON article_tags.article_id = ID_OF_ARTICLE_WE_WANT_CATEGORIES_FROM
```

In your query, the table article_tags isn't actually joined to anything else. Looking at the schema you provided, it seems `article_tags` is related to `tags` via (`article_tags.tag_id` -> `tags.id`)

Try this query:

```
SELECT tags.* 
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN categories ON tags.id = categories.tag_id
INNER JOIN article_tags ON article_tags.article_id = tags.id
WHERE article_tags.article_id = :user_input
```